# Can you use Timecop gem for development In Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I found time travelling gems like Timecop, to *test* time dependent features. Is it possible and/or sensible to use this in *development* as well?

If not: is there another time traveller gem, suitable for development? I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, sure you can. Here's some example code from an app I've built, where you can set a date via the admin area, and then browse the site as if it's that date, for the duration of your session:

in `app/controllers/concerns/time_travel_filters.rb`:

```
# This allows us to set a different date
# in the admin area, and use TimeCop to process each
# request as being on that different date - useful for
# testing different phases of the challenge.
module TimeTravelFilters
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.staging?
      around_filter :time_travel_for_request
    end
  end

  def time_travel_for_request
    time_travel
    yield
    time_travel_return
  end

  def time_travel
    logger.info 'TIME TRAVEL START'
    if session[:timecop_date]
      Timecop.travel(session[:timecop_date])
    else
      Timecop.return
    end
  end

  def time_travel_return
    logger.info 'TIME TRAVEL RETURN'
    Timecop.return
  end
end
```

and then you just need to `include TimeTravelFilters` in your controllers that you want to use it.

You'll need to set `session[:timecop_date]` in order for it to take effect - I do this through a form on a page in my admin area, but you can do it however you want. Returning to the current time is as simple as deleting that session key.

Comment: Still works on Rails 5+, but you must use `around_action` instead of `around_filter`.

Comment: I've created a gem with your solution and UI to let user time travel https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/rails_time_travel